# Installing facebook comments in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook-comments

I've used the same plugin across a couple wordpress sites (with different facebook app IDs) but this latest install doesnt work. The Facebook comment box is not visible on the blog posts despite the rest of the plugin test showing up. (Powered by facebook comments etc...) The site is www.Phalgeron.com Chrome inspect element console shows the following 3 errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'provide'

http://c.gigcount.com/wildfire/IMP/CXNID=2000002.0NXC/bT*xJmx*PTEyOTc5MjcxNzkyMTQmcHQ9MTI5NzkyNzE4Njc*OCZwPTI3MDgxJmQ9cHJvX3BsYXllcl9maXJzdF9nZW4mZz*xJm89/ODQ4ODJiMGE3OWUwNDZiNzg5NGY3YmFkMjE5Y2E*Mzcmb2Y9MA==.gif
Failed to load resource

http://phalgeron.com/crossdomain.xml Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Example URLs would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention what your plugin is. You could enter the comment code manually, it's really simple and easy:

Add the fb app ID meta to the HTML header section:

```
<meta property='fb:app_id' content='YOUR APP ID' />
```

Place this right after the  call, on your comments.php file or your page template if the comments.php is not used:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>  
<fb:comments href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" width="880"></fb:comments>
```

As an extra bonus, if you want to add a comment count somewhere use this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&permalink=1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:130px; height:16px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Check, style and profit!